# Protractor/Jasmine Undefined variable issue

Tags: protractor

why in the below code the variable username1 is undefined? username is valid howeverand returns the expected value:

```
var AngularHomePage = function() {
  this.nameInput = element(by.model('yourName'));
  this.greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));

  this.get = function() {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
  };

  this.setName = function() {
    var username;
    var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader('../spece2e/sneh.csv', {
      'columnsFromHeader': false,
      'separator': ','
    });
    reader.addListener('data', function(data) {
      username = data[0];
      console.log('data from csv is: ',username);
      //return username;                
    });
    return username;    
  };

  var username1=this.setName();
  console.log('data being sent: ',username1);
  this.nameInput.sendKeys(username1);
};

module.exports=new AngularHomePage();
```

Comment: Is the `addListener` callback ever called? If not, you never set a value to `username` so the default value is `undefined`. Even if the function is, it might be a matter of timing. Adding a listener (generally speaking -- I don't know what `csv` represents here or how it is implemented`) does not execute the function synchronously.

Comment: console.log('data from csv is:')  gives correct data but after that the username variable becomes undefined.

Comment: your `username` variable is declared into  the `setName` function, what do you get when assigning `var foo = setName();`?

Comment: it became undefined again

Comment: You mean that `data[0]` contains a value, but `foo` which get the result of the `return` is `undefined`, right?

Comment: username inside the setName function has the correct value as data[0] but username1 is undefined

Comment: Did you try: `var username1 = AngularHomePage.setName()`? ;)